# How to get POST params in beforeFilter in AppController?

Tags: cakephp, post, controller, request

I would like to know how can i get POST params of request to any controller (whole app)?

I tried to do it by this way:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    var_dump( $this->request->data);
    die();
}
```

But response is an empty array.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Which version of CakePHP? This works with CakePHP 2.5 (and I think with at least all CakePHP version above 2.0).

Comment: Is it last stable release. I need post params from the JSON post request to API.

Answer (score 1):

Call `parent::beforeFilter();` in the Controller function, then you will be able to access the request data by `$this->request->data`;

[Click here](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html) for more details on before Filter.

Answer (score 0):

I searched it now and found out that beforefilter by default gets executed before any controller function. Try doing it in different way,like print_r($this->request->data); exit;

Comment: I think that POST data are available before any controller action it depends on Apache (or any other web server)